# Seperating patch panel and switch in different rooms

Tags: patch-panel

I am wiring a department in an enterprise environment with cat6 cabling. My server room will be in a separate room from the patch panel . All the wiring will be terminated at a patch panel at the other side of the building.

I want to keep the switch in the server room but I do not want to run every port back to the patch panel. Is there a way to run all the signals from the patch panel to the server room. The only thing I can think of is a fiber channel but then I need a device in the patch panel room and it defeats the purpose. From some feedback it appears to run a remote switch at the patch panel and uplink it to a switch in the server room with a dedicated high speed drop. I would like to eliminate and equipment in the patch panel room but cannot find any other work around.

Thanks

Comment: Home networking is off topic here, but no there's no way to do so, your best (and only) option is still to have the switch in the patch panel.

Comment: Don't wire your house.  WiFi delivers more than enough bandwidth

Comment: @RonRoyston: I think this highly depends on the use case. You cannot say that WiFi is always sufficient, not even in home environments. To topic: use two switches of you really need one in your server room. But you will want to use one switch to terminate the patch panel connections.

Comment: @waza-ari No.  Wrong.  15 Mbps necessary for 4K ultra HD streaming.  Much less than that for normal HD streaming.  802.11ac > SATA III link.  I'm sure you can come up with a far fetched what if, but practically speaking: don't wire your house.

Comment: Unless you need stupid bandwidth, then a single 10Gbps drop and two switches, one in the basement and one in the server room will cover your requirements.  The 10Gbps link can trunk multiple VLANs, there are relatively inexpensive switches available now with a couple of 10G ports.

Comment: thanks for the comments... I think an dedicated uplink 10Gbps or fiber for more bandwidth is the best option. As for wi-fi : while the bandwidth is sufficient there are latency issues and interference issues that can slow the network down.

Comment: Updated post to fit this site. Thanks JFL. Also sounds like that is the best solution to put a simple unmanaged switch in the patch panel room and uplink it to the the server room where the managed switch is. It is important for the managed switch to be in the server room if there is a remote connection issue and a direct connection needs to be made to it. thanks again

Comment: You changed "my 2 story house" to "a department in an enterprise environment". That's lying to try to make this on topic.

Comment: @TeunVink Not lying - I work in an enterprise environment and I want to know this answer as it comes up now and again. I am an electrical engineer and worked in the IT industry for over 25 years. Looking for any new tech solutions. Thanks anyway Teun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would trunk vlan's to another switch in the basement .You can use two Cisco switches to accomplish this relatively easy.